# Wikidata SPARQL get current VALUES index

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I have the current SPARQL code:

```
SELECT ?currentQid ?propQid ?targetQid WHERE
{
  VALUES ?current {wd:Q5 wd:Q6 wd:Q7 wd:Q8 wd:Q9}
  VALUES ?prop {wdt:P31 wdt:P279 wdt:P361}
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?current), STR(wd:)) AS ?currentQid)
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?prop), STR(wdt:)) AS ?propQid)
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?target), STR(wd:)) AS ?targetQid)
  ?current ?prop ?target.
}
ORDER BY ASC (?currentQid)
```

([w.wiki/3Gn](http://w.wiki/3Gn))

Which outputs

```
currentQid  propQid  targetQid
    Q5        P31    Q55983715
    Q5        P279   Q154954
    Q5        P279   Q215627
    Q5        P361   Q1156970
    Q8        P31    Q331769
    Q8        P31    Q60539479
    Q8        P279   Q16748867
```

However, I wanted to also have the current index of the value, so I can correctly attribute the values to the array's item when I get the JSON.

How could I get the following table?

```
index  currentQid  propQid  targetQid
  0        Q5        P31    Q55983715
  0        Q5        P279   Q154954
  0        Q5        P279   Q215627
  0        Q5        P361   Q1156970
  3        Q8        P31    Q331769
  3        Q8        P31    Q60539479
  3        Q8        P279   Q16748867
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VALUES` are unordered; SPARQL list syntax is also not allowed in `VALUES`. The simplest option is explicit ordering:

```
SELECT ?index ?currentQid ?propQid ?targetQid WHERE
{ 
  VALUES (?current ?index) {(wd:Q5 0) (wd:Q6 1) (wd:Q7 2) (wd:Q8 3) (wd:Q9 4)}
  VALUES ?prop {wdt:P31 wdt:P279 wdt:P361}
  ?current ?prop ?target. 
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?current), STR(wd:)) AS ?currentQid)
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?prop), STR(wdt:)) AS ?propQid)
  BIND (STRAFTER(STR(?target), STR(wd:)) AS ?targetQid)
}
ORDER BY ASC (xsd:integer(STRAFTER(?currentQid, 'Q')))
```

[Try it](https://w.wiki/3HA)